# Need help on downloading a text file from a site using HttpsUrlConnection java class

Tags: java

I want to read the content of a text file which is located in the site

**https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt**

I want to read it using Java . I started it with using HttpsUrlConnection Class .

When we take the above URL in the browser , we will first redirect to a agreement page and if we click the agree button , we can see the text file . How we can do the same procedure using HttpsUrlConnection class ?

This is what I tried:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement?agreementValue=Agree");
HttpsURLConnection   https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
https.setRequestMethod("POST");

https.connect();

url = new URL("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt");
HttpsURLConnection  http = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("GET");           
http.connect();

String line = "";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(http.getInputStream()));
while( (line = in.readLine()) != null )
{System.out.println(line);
    //process line
    logger.debug(line);
    processLine(line);
}
http.disconnect();
```

Any inputs will be highly appreciable

Comment: Please provide some code illustrating your attempts.

Comment: I've looked a bit at the network traffic, you have to agree to the terms which is done through a http post of the agreement form. You could try to simulate this by first posting the agreement form, and then in the same session request the txt. (Note: you should check if this is allowed, since your app will try to download content without the user actually agreeing!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the POST request to accept the agreement results in a session cookie from the server which likely stores whether or not the agreement is accepted.  You could try getting the JSESSIONID cookie from the "Set-Cookie" header and sending it in your "Cookie" header to simulate the behaviour of the browser.